# ¿Cómo crear una secuencia de autoincremento que inserte un ID que fue eliminado?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Necesito ayuda en lo siguiente:
Resulta que tengo una  secuencia en Oracle que genera mediante un Trigger un ID cuando se inserta una nueva Row de forma incremental hasta 5.

```
ID TEXTO
1  'Manzanas'
2  'Naranjas'
3  'Peras'
4  'Frutillas'
5  'Platanos'
```

El problema esta cuando yo elimino una row como por ejemplo `2 'Naranjas'` al hacer un insert arroja un error ya que la secuencia ya llego hasta 5.
Necesito que cuando se haga este insert tome el ID que falte en la secuencia del 1 al 5, en este caso el `ID 2` y lo inserte.

Tengo la siguiente Tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Categorias (
      ID_CATEGORIA NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
      NUM_POSICION NUMBER(3),
      ID_TEXTO NUMBER(6)
 );

CREATE SEQUENCE Categorias_SEQUENCE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Categorias_ON_INSERT
    BEFORE INSERT ON Categorias
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SELECT CATEGORIA_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.ID_CATEGORIA
    FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Comment: Por favor, [edit] tu pregunta y comparte lo que llevas hecho hasta el momento.

Comment: ESto que estas pidiendo suena rarisimo... ademas que las secuencias no se usan asi.. podrias explicar porque necesitarias algo asi?